# How to create a relatively positioned footer

Tags: html, css

I want to make footer like all other footers. Deep bottom and stays there. But on the other hand I want its top side to be expandable depending on the position of div.content. It might be constant value like 10px. So if div.content moves to top it moves to (while still keeping the bottom of the screen as footer). How can I do this?

```css
.main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}
.left-content {
  float: left;
  margin: 2.27272727272727%;
  /* 20/880 = 0.0227272727272727 */
  width: 56.81818181818182%;
  /* 500/880 = 0.5681818181818182 */
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
.right-content {
  float: left;
  margin: 2.27272727272727%;
  /* 20/880 = 0.0227272727272727 */
  width: 34.09090909090909%;
  /* 300/880 = 0.3409090909090909 */
  background-color: mediumturquoise;
}
.inner-content {
  float: left;
  margin: 2%;
  /* 10/500 = 0.02 */
  width: 44%;
  /* 220/500 = 0.44 */
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
.footer {
  clear: both;
  height: 10%;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left-content">
      <h1>A</h1>
      <p>asd</p>
      <p>asd</p>
      <p>asd</p>
      <p>asd</p>
      <p>asd</p>
      <div class="inner-content">
        <h1>D</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="inner-content">
        <h1>D</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-content">
      <h1>B</h1>
      <p>asd</p>
      <p>asd</p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h1>C</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to keep the footer on the bottom of the screen no matter what. Correct?

To do this, add the following to your footer class.

```
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
```